# Hide "ActionBar" on API 21

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-5.0-lollipop

I've updated Androïd SDK yesterday, so I have change the `targetSdkVersion` to 21.
Since I did this update I am unable to hide the "ActionBar" (which is not realy one) on an Activity.

In my application there is just one Activity that I want to display without title bar and without actionbar.

All activities used this theme:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
</style>
```

and I tried this in the concerned activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    this.supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
}
```

but it doesn't work.
I also tried : `getSupportActionBar().hide()` but `getSupportActionBar()` returns `null`

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `getActionBar().hide()` like this.

```
public class MyActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity);

        this.getActionBar().hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: getActionBar() also returns null so this line makes application crash.

Comment: Ok! I did it in the onCreate method but before super.onCreate ... I moved the instruction after super.onCreate() and it works. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I have an application with an Activity without the action bar applying this style :

```
<style name="AppBaseThemeNoActionBar" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

After switching the project on API 21, it did not worked anymore so I had to change the style to :

```
<style name="AppBaseThemeNoActionBar" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
</style>
```

Of course you have to apply it in the AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<activity
    android:name=".activities.ActivitySplash"
    android:theme="@style/AppBaseThemeNoActionBar">
</activity>
```

Documentation : http://android-developers.blogspot.be/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html

Answer (score 1):

The above solution with the `getActionbar().hide()` didn't work for me so i decided to use the following:

Just create a new theme which is an extension of your current theme and remove the toolbar from it

```
public class YourActivity extends ActionBarActivity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setTheme(R.style.YourTheme_NoTitleBar);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_your);

        //...
    }
}
```

Example of a Possible Theme definition

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="YourTheme" parent="YourTheme.Base"/>

    <style name="YourTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="colorPrimary">YOURCOLOR1</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">YOURCOLOR2</item>

        <!-- to show toolbar, be careful if windowNoTitle is set to true it will show the toolbar-->
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">true</item>

        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/YOURCOLOR3</item>
    </style>

    <style name="YourTheme.NoTitleBar" parent="YourTheme">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Notice the `.NoTitleBar` This can be anything but i took this to make it logical, just make sure both values there are correctly set. if `windowActionBar` is set to false but `android:windowNoTitle` is still false then it will still show the toolbar!

The official docs http://android-developers.blogspot.be/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html

Answer (score 0):

Instead of extending to ActionBarActivity ,extentds your MainActivity class to Activity i.e

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity);


    }
}
```